# Property with '= {return}()' or '{return}'?

Tags: swift

There are two ways in Swift to declare complicated property:

*option1:*

```
var label: UILabel {
    var label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 18.0)
    return label
}
```

*option2:*

```
var label: UILabel = {
    var label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 18.0)
    return label
}()
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

option1 declares a computed property, every time you invoke the property, the result would be re-computed. Computed property is often used to replace computing function. And computed property cannot be declared by `let`

option2 declares a label and customizes it. It is not a computed property which means it can also be declared as a constant. It can be used as a normal property.

Answer (score 3):

The asnwer provided by @Carrl is good, but I would clarify some things with option2:
What you assign to label in option2, it is actually a closure, and the `()` means at the and of the curly brackets, that you execute the closure right away.
So imagine:

```
let labelClosure: () -> UILabel = {
    var label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 18.0)
    println("here2")
    return label
}
```

This is the closure that you assign to label in option2, but this is just a function, without executed (see, there are no `()` at the end of the curly brackets). So if you want to create a label from that, you should write:

```
labelClosure()
```

So wrap things up: in option2 you assign the closures return value to label, in opposition to option1, which is a computed property. And what does a computed property mean? Actually, that doesn't store any value, it just computes and returns its value every time you call it.

Comment: Still not clear. Can someone explain to me in different words?