# Swift: Why "()" needed after closure if "()->" missing before type?

Tags: swift, closures

next code is correct, but I don't understand 
why "()" needed after closure,
if "()->" missing before type?

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    /*lazy var personalizedGreeting: ()->String = {
        [unowned self] in
        return "Hello, \(self.name)!"
    }*/
    lazy var personalizedGreeting: String = {
        [unowned self] in
        return "Hello, \(self.name)!"
        }()
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
let person = Person(name: "John Doe")
print(person.personalizedGreeting)
```

Comment: Related: [Property with '= {return}()' or '{return}'?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28792014/2976878) – [what do parenthesis do after lazy var definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35237786/2976878)

Comment: @mlev: Note that `personalizedGreeting`  is a *string,* not a closure.

Comment: Yeah @MartinR, they certainly qualify as dupes, I just held off because I had a better dupe target in mind – but can't seem to find, so nevermind :)

Comment: @MartinR This question is more generic, and could lead to a better answer than the very specific and unclear one on the question marked as a duplicate, I think. But I'm...